# Php Oauth1 using GET Method

Tags: php, netsuite

I need to create Oauth1 request in php to Netsuite System using Get Method.
I can't understand what is wrong. I always receive 403 LOGIN NOT ATTEMPT.
My parameters are type and customerId

My code:

```
$oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());
        $oauth_timestamp = time();
        $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
        $oauth_version = "1.0";

        $base_string =
            "GET&" . urlencode($url) . "&" .
            urlencode(
                "deploy=" . "1"
                 ."&customerId=" . $customerID
                 ."&type=" . $type
                . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . $consumerKey
                . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
                . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
                . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
                . "&oauth_token=" . $token
                . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
                . "&realm=" . $realm
                . "&script=" . $script
            );
        $sig_string = urlencode($consumerSecret) . '&' . urlencode($tokenSecret);
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $sig_string, true));

        $auth_header = "OAuth "
            . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
            . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '", '
            . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '", '
            . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '", '
            . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode($consumerKey) . '", '
            . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode($token) . '", '
            . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '", '
            . 'realm="' . rawurlencode($realm) .'"';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?&script=' . $script . '&deploy=' . "1" . '&realm=' . $realm. "&customerId=" . $customerID."&type=" . $type);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Authorization: ' . $auth_header,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ]);

        $Acode  = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $Aresult = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        curl_close($ch);
```